# Declaratively update markup inside component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component in my app that renders some data, most commonly a page title.

**Markup**:

```
<Toolbar>
  <ToolbarRow>
    <div id="title-bar">
      {children}
    </div>
  </ToolbarRow>
</Toolbar>
```

How would I declaratively be able to change the data inside?

I've tried `react-side-effects` which allowed me to indeed change the title to be rendered but then I wanted to be able to add components as well.

Components aren't to be stored inside state so there's that…

Then I looked at Portals, which seem to exactly what I want but I get `Target container is not a DOM element.`

**Markup for the portal component**:

```
import React from "react";
import {createPortal} from 'react-dom'

const PageTitle = ({title, children}) => {
  return createPortal(
    <p>foo</p>,
    document.getElementById('title-bar')
  )
};

export default PageTitle;
```

I'm calling the portal component like so:

```
<PageTitle title="Document Overview"/>
```

As you can see from the above snippet, the other component adds a `<div id="title-bar" />`, so I guess it has to do with timing.

Anyone have a good idea?

Comment: `children` is _basically_ an array of React components. Why don't clone it and store it in a variable, makes the changes you want, then include it in your `render` function/template?

Comment: I want to be able to update `{children}` from anywhere. Say I render `<PageTitle title="Document Overview"/>` on a different page with a different title, I want the actual markup (The Toolbar one) to update with the new title.

Comment: This way I can add a `PageTitle` component wherever to update the page's title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just put components into the state here:

```
  const bars = [];

  export class TitleBar extends Component {
    state = { children: [] };

    componentDidMount() { bars.push(this); }
    componentWillUnmount() { bars.splice(bars.indexOf(this), 1); }
    render() { return this.state.children };
 }

 const RealPageTitle = ({ title }) => <div> { title } </div>;

 export class PageTitle extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.real = RealPageTitle(props);
   }

   componentDidMount() {
     for(const bar of bars)
       bar.setState(({ children }) => ({ children: children.concat(this.real) }));
   }

   componentWillUnmount() {
     for(const bar of bars)
      bar.setState(({ children }) => ({ children: children.filter(child => child !== this.real) }));
   }

   render() { }
 }
```

That way you can just add `<PageTitle title={"Test"} />` somewhere on the page and it gets added to the title bar.

*I know this does not follow "best practices", but it certainly works*

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This was kind of my last hope. Managed to get it to work using contexts =)

Comment: In the end I did end up adding it to the state anyways. Thanks!